# System can't verify shared libraries

Tags: macos, shared-libraries, macos-monterey

I have a program executable that uses quite a few shared libraries. However when attempting to download and run it on another computer I get an error saying that the program can't be opened because the libraries cannot be verified. The only way to run it is to manually go into system preferences and allow each individual library. Is there any way to get the libraries verified so that the program can be run normally?

Comment: macOS system versions in question?  App is notarized?

Comment: It is macOS Monertey 12.0.1 It is not notarized it is just a compiled project built in eclipse with c++ and SDL2. The SDL2 libraries are what cannot be verified not the  project itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library Validation ensures dynamically-loaded libraries are signed off by the same entity which signs the main executable.

Per [Apple: Code Signing Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH4-SW9):

> A program may link against any library with the same team identifier
> in its code signature as the main executable, or with any Apple system
> library. Requests to link against other libraries are denied.

To get the libraries validated, they must be codesigned with the same identity. Your identity would look something like this, depending on your certificate type: `"Developer ID Application: Firstname Lastname (XXXXXXXXXX)"`  The required team identifier is the ten-character code in parentheses.  The entire string in double-quotes is the *common name* of the certificate used.

```
codesign -s "Developer ID Application: Doctor Who (1234567890)" path/to/binary
```

###### Caveat: Once you get beyond library validation: macOS 12 will attempt to verify the team identity by the stapled notary ticket or by looking up the ticket on Apple servers in the cloud. Without notarizing, no problem *for your own machine* as there is no need to validate the self. In macOS 12 the Notary/sandbox/library validation/hardened runtime security scheme is enforced by default.